# Homoclinic orbits of cubic potential

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I found in Carles Simo's 'Hamiltonian Systems with Three or More Degrees of Freedom', among other references, that the homoclinic orbit for the cubic potential
 $\frac{y^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{2}}{2}$ is $\Gamma=\{(x_{0}(t),y_{0}(t))\}$ where $x_{0}(t)=(\sqrt{3}/2)(cosh(t/2))^{-2}$, $y_{0}(u)=\dot{x}_{0}(u)$. Does anybody know how to obtain this or has a good reference? I don't even know where to start! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Certainly you know how to find the equilibria. So just take the derivative of $x_0$.

Comment: That's verifying that $x_{0}$ is the solution, I want to get to that solution somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've switched $x$ and $y$ in your description, since the function $x_0(t)$ does not obey $\frac{\dot{x}_0^2}{2} + \frac{\dot{x}_0^3}{3}- \frac{x_0^2}{2} = \text{constant}$. Moreover, if you want to interpret the conserved quantity (Hamiltonian? Lagrangian?) $E = \frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{x^2}{2}$ as one having a 'cubic potential', then this implies that $\dot{y} = x$, and not the other way around. Also, you've made a mistake in the prefactor of $x_0$, as this function does not obey $F = \frac{x_0^2}{2} + \frac{x_0^3}{3}- \frac{\dot{x}_0^2}{2} = \text{constant}$. To remedy this, substitute $x = \frac{a}{cosh^2 \frac{t}{2}}$ and try to see for which value of $a$ you do get a constant value (hint: the constant value is zero).

To get an idea of how to obtain such an explicit expression, you can solve the quadratic equation $\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}- \frac{\dot{x}^2}{2} = 0$ for $\dot{x}$ to obtain a first order ODE for $x(t)$, which you then can solve using [standard methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Alternative_notation).

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I just modified the potential.

Comment: To solve this, I would write $\dot{x}=\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{2}{3}x^{3}}$, hence I have $dt=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{2}{3}x^{3}}}$ and then I integrate in [0,x*]?

Comment: another typo, $x^{2}-\frac{2}{3}x^{3}$

Comment: Yes, that would be a sensible approach. Feel free to accept the answer if you're happy with it, btw