# Solution to nonlinear ODE with square root

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-integration, cauchy-principal-value

How do I solve the following equation?
$\dot{x}=\sqrt{x^{2}-\frac{2}{3}x^{3}}$ with $x(0)=0$? I'm guessing I have to work with $dt=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{2}-\frac{2}{3}x^{3}}}$ and integrate in [0,t'] $\Leftrightarrow$ [0,x'] but I'm having problems around $x=0$

Comment: is here $x=x(t)$?

Comment: yes, exactly!!!

Comment: Then $x(t)=0$ for every $t$.

Comment: That's the trivial solution, but there are other solutions. I think there's one involving sech or something like that

Comment: Given that the general solution is $$\ln|x|-2\ln\left(\sqrt{1-\frac23x}+1\right)=t+C$$ I don't see how you are going to match that with $x(0)=0$. The singular solution seems to be all there is.

Comment: This is what I've done so far, but I don't seem to be getting the solution I expected... 
$dt=dx/\sqrt{x^{2}-\frac{2}{3}x^{3}} \Rightarrow t=\int_{0}^{x’}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-2x/3}}$
Defining $u^{2}=1-2x/3$, then $x=3(1-u^{2})/2$ and $dx=-3udu$.
Hence, replacing in our integral,
t=$\int_{0}^{x’}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-2x/3}}=\int_{0}^{u’}\frac{-2du}{1-u^{2}}$
And considering the partial fractions expansion,
$t=ln(\frac{1-u’}{1+u’})=ln(\frac{3}{x}-1-\sqrt{\frac{9}{x^{2}}-\frac{6}{x}})=arccosh(\frac{3}{x}-1)$
Finally, as $t=arccosh(\frac{3-x}{x})$, we get $x=\frac{3}{1+cosh(t)}$

Comment: You were right, I can only get the trivial solution with x(0)=0. I can get other solutions, as I showed before, with $x(\infty)=0$ for example.

Comment: Your ODE is differentiable in $x=0$, thus having a unique solution there. There might be complications with solutions starting in $x(0)=\frac32$, but that was not asked after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787227/homoclinic-orbits-of-cubic-potential): you know that the answer will be of the form $x(t) = \frac{a}{\text{cosh}^2 t/2}$. Then, what is $x(0)$? It also helps to sketch the graph of $\frac{1}{\text{cosh}^2 t/2}$. What do you notice? Do you see why $x(0) = 0$ yields the trivial solution, as @Did pointed out?

So, given that you have to take a nonzero initial condition $x(0) = x_0 \neq 0$, separation of variables yields
\begin{equation}
 t = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{\xi^2 - \frac{2}{3} \xi^3}}\text{d}\xi.
\end{equation}
To calculate the integral, it's useful to rewrite the integrand as $\frac{1}{\xi \sqrt{1-\frac{2}{3}\xi}}$ and introduce the new variable $\eta = \sqrt{1-\frac{2}{3}\xi}$, such that $\xi = \frac{3}{2}(1-\eta^2)$, and thus $\text{d} \xi = - 3 \eta \,\text{d} \eta$. To calculate the new integral, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function#Derivatives) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks Frits! Luckily I managed to solve this some comments before :)